# Can I revert a changeset and keep the later changeset intact

Tags: mercurial

Suppose we have

- changeset 14
- changeset 15
- changeset 16

and I am on changeset 16 and I need to take out the changes I made in changeset #14 but keeping #15 and #16 intact.

Can I do this with hg? I feel like it's impossible because changeset #15 and #16 depends on #14.... I heard about queue patches. Is it relevant?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the [backout](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Backout) command. It does just what you want. It'll remove the changes in chageset 14 and attempt to apply the later changes, asking you if it can't make sense due to lost information.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just used it and it worked!  `hg backout -r <rev # to remove>` Thanks!